# How do I find the path for the DLLs used by the accessible_output lib?

Tags: python, accessibility

I am a blind programmer and I am trying  to develop an application to retrieve automatically the  lyrics from the current playing song on Winamp and present it in an accessible way to screen readers.
I am using accessible_output, a lib that makes easier the process of making the active screen reader speaks with the user.
You can find it here:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/accessible_output/0.7.5#id3
It requires the DLL  from the screen reader to work. In my tests, NVDA screen reader, it needs the NVDA32controller.dll. 
When running from the command line,it works well, but after  creating an .exe file with py2exe, it does not find the dll, so the screen reader does not speak anymore...
Any ideas how to solve this problem? I looked on the source code of the lib and maybe the path that the lib is looking for just works when it is executed from the command line, but when it is an .exe file, it changes... but I don't know why. Maybe I should add another path, but what path it should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article here seems to describe a similar problem and a solution (packing the DLL in question): http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/10/09/packaging-dlls-with-executable-made-by-py2exe/

In addition, independent of the article above, IIRC Windows looks inside a program's installation directory for DLLs. Copying the DLL for the screen reader to the directory where the py2exe program resides might work. This solution does not deploy too well though and the one above although similar could be better.

Comment: thank you. This tutorial helped me. Also, I found the argument of the setup function called data_files, where I can add tuples informing the folders to be created and the files to be copied